# OS X Notification Center Font

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I want to have in my app a Notification Center like font, e.g. this white crisp font with the black outline, but I struggle to get it done in IB.

Does anyone know what font type, size, etc apple uses, and how to reproduce them ?

Answer (score 0):

For the app names the text appears to be Lucida Grande 14 bold with a black drop shadow.  It was difficult to determine the exact drop shadow parameters but I think it is black with offsets of -1.